# Is there any way to directly import Outlook 2003 .pab (Personal Address Book) into Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, import, contacts

On a new PC I have installed Office 2013. Earlier I had Office 2003 and therein I had created Personal Address Book (.pab) file.

However I am unable to import that .pab into Outlook 2013 Contacts. It appears that such an option does not exist in Outlook 2013. Under File -> Import/Export the only 'File Type' options available are CSV & PST.

Is there any way to somehow directly import Outlook 2003's .PAB file into Contacts in Outlook 2013?

I have searched the net but there is no clear information available. It appears that Outlook 2013 does not have any concept of PAB files and other places it talks about Office 2010 only.

I want to avoid going back to Office 2003 and export contacts to .CSV therein and then use that file to import into Outlook 2013.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Outlook 2007 was the last version that had an import feature for .pab files.  I know that 2013 and 2016 only have import options for .csv or .pst files.  Beginning in 2007 the address book became contacts and is now part of the .pst file.

I think your options are to go back to 2003 and export the .pab as .csv or find someone that is still running 2007 and ask them if you can load and convert your .pab

Answer (score 0):

If you have backup of PST file created in Outlook 2003, you can do this by creating separate PST file for contacts and then simply configure this file with Outlook 2013.

Check out this post for more information: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1852562-importing-contacts-in-outlook-2007-from-pst